# when running sqlite database on emulator I get the "failed to load dynamic library" exception

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, android-emulator

everytime i try and run my app on a android emulator i get this error

```
Exception has occurred.
SqfliteFfiException (SqfliteFfiException(error, Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library '/data/data/com.example.the_holy_trinity/lib/libsqlite3.so': dlopen failed: library "/data/data/com.example.the_holy_trinity/lib/libsqlite3.so" not found}) DatabaseException(Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library '/data/data/com.example.the_holy_trinity/lib/libsqlite3.so': dlopen failed: library "/data/data/com.example.the_holy_trinity/lib/libsqlite3.so" not found))
```

This is the first time I have ever tried using an emulator so I really dont know what info I am meant to share here so please please please if you need anymore information than what is here please let me know and I will share it.

If you know anything I would **really** appreciate it
thank you so so much in advance